# Постоянно не работают кнопки ctrl C, ctrl z, ctrl P в atom

Tags: linux, ubuntu, atom

Постоянно при работе в ubuntu в atom.
Перестают работать кнопки <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> и.т.д.

Потом опять переключаюсь на другие программы проходит какое то время и снова начинают работать.

Как будто в системе или в atom идёт переключение набора горячих клавиш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, с чем это связано, но я сталкивался с этой проблемой в ситуации, когда клавиатура в состоянии "кириллица". Причём некоторые программы ведут себя вполне нормально, а некоторые требуют, что была обязательно включена латиница. Особенно это достаёт в KDevelop, которым пользуюсь каждый день.